# How do i get an MKAnnotationView's coords?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a method like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Using this, can i get the coordinates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
return view.annotation.coordinate;
```

- `.annotation` property: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW7
- `.coordinate` property: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008208-CH1-SW2